# Ajax Doesn't work in Chrome,Firefox, & Opera

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

below is my function on main page.this code works fine in IE, please check where i am doing mistake

i just want to pass values to ajax page as you can see my link above.

```
  function showUser2(str2)
  {

  if (str2=="")
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

 var drdownValue = document.getElementsByName('shorting').item(0).value;
 var buttonValue1 = document.getElementsByName('buttonpassvalue1').item(0).value;

     var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').value, 10);
     value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
     value++;
     document.getElementById('count').value = value;

var val123 = document.getElementById('count').value.trim();    
var gotnumber = document.getElementById('getpagevalue').value.trim();    

     if(val123 > gotnumber){
        buttonpassvalue1.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        buttonpassvalue.removeAttribute("disabled");

     }    else{
        buttonpassvalue.removeAttribute("disabled");
        buttonpassvalue1.removeAttribute("disabled");
     }

 alert(drdownValue);// to check click and value
 alert(buttonValue1);// to check click and value

 xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + drdownValue + "&version1=" + buttonValue1, true);

 xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

button html code

```
<button class="button" type="button" name="buttonpassvalue1" value="1" onclick="showUser2(this.value)">Next >> </button>
```

this code works fine in IE, please check where i am doing mistake

i just want to pass values to ajax page as you can see my link above.

thanks

Comment: why don't you put a breakpoint and debug it? also jquery would be a good choice if you can use it on your project...

Comment: raw ajax makes me cry, considered jquery? of course jquery makes other people cry.

Comment: i read somewhere it could be due to button not inside form...i don't have form for above button....but still works in IE

Comment: I don't know why everyone demands using a library without knowing anything about the project. The libraries all use these functions anyway...

Comment: no luck...fail again...any help pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: any logs in console, like exceptions and warnings?

Comment: no one demanded you use a library it was just a suggestion. be nive to the *free* help

Comment: please check and access link in both IE and chrome will give you can idea...http://jsfiddle.net/tC2Wd/

Comment: check the nav. on right bottom..

Comment: @Merlin please check above link

Comment: @Dagon please check above link

Comment: hi @FashFootwear , the url is your localhost which I cann't access to that since the localhost will direct me to my local instead of yours.

Comment: sure send me your pc, then i can access your localhost :-)

Comment: @FashFootwear The point of jsfiddle isn't to just copy/paste a link to your computer - it's to set up a working example which demonstrates the problem. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/y6XgY/) for an example of how it should be used

Comment: Looks like W3Schools strikes again: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use jQuery or other framework, that will be always aware of all the browsers specific stuff.

If you prefer to use native code, you will need some extra code. First, dont rely just in `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` and `XMLHttpRequest` that probably wont be always available. instead of that, use:

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}

var xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
```

then you define your callback:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
```

and send it, but i would include a random variable in the url, to ensure that the browser is not caching anything

```
xmlHttp.open("GET",url+"&sid="+Math.random(),true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

**Anyways,** probably your problem has nothing to do with the ajax itself, and probably there is something else in your code causing everything to crash.

For example, take a look at the chrome console, and im sure you will have some useful informtion in the error log. if you dont know how, here you have a [guide](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Answer (score 0):

First, I have cleaned up your code a bit:

```
function showUser2(str2){

  if (str2==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "productlistajax.php?q=" + drdownValue + "&version1=" + buttonValue1, true);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
  }

   var drdownValue = document.getElementsByName('shorting').item(0).value;
   var buttonValue1 = document.getElementsByName('buttonpassvalue1').item(0).value;

   var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('count').value, 10);
   value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
   value++;
   document.getElementById('count').value = value;

   var val123 = document.getElementById('count').value.trim();    
   var gotnumber = document.getElementById('getpagevalue').value.trim();    

   if(val123 > gotnumber){
        buttonpassvalue1.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        buttonpassvalue.removeAttribute("disabled");

   }else{
        buttonpassvalue.removeAttribute("disabled");
        buttonpassvalue1.removeAttribute("disabled");
   }

   alert(drdownValue);// to check click and value
   alert(buttonValue1);// to check click and value


   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Note that I have moved xmlHTTP.open in front of xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange.

If this doesn't fix your issue, please remove the non-essential code so that I can better understand your intent.

jQuery in your case will only save a few lines of code. You CAN write compact, robust and maintainable JavaScript code. I signed up StackOverflow specifically so that I can share my knowledge about plain ol' JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome,Firefox, & Opera do not support Microsoft objects. You are using

```
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

In chrome, this line gives me this error:

> **ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined**

You'll have to get your data in a cross-browser compatible way. This can be using jQuery or plain Javascript

Comment: I don't believe this is the problem, it's checking if `XMLHttpRequest` is supported and if not, falling back to `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`. Luckily for me, I haven't had to support IE recently but this used to be the standard non-jQuery way to do this

Comment: @Basic yes, you're right. I didn't piece everything together properly