# JS - AJAX works on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have a problem with this code below. It runs perfectly on firefox v50.X but doesn't work on chrome v55.X.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function load(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "name.html", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="submit" onclick="load();">
   <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**name.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Test.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this code not working on chrome?

Comment: Please provide the error from Google Chrome's Developper Console. You can find it in `Parameters --> More tools --> Development Tools`. It will open a new window from which you should see the tab Console.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but have you tried taking the `<html>` and `<body>` tags out of name.html? They shouldn't be in there if you're loading the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
var xmlHttp=null;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  }
return xmlHttp;
}

var xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225411/ajax-doesnt-work-in-chrome-firefox-opera)